# Tags: archaeology vs. archeology

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tag [archaeology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaeology) has a description and 37 questions.

The tag [archeology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archeology) has no description and 2 questions.

They should be merged (into `archæology` :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wish is my command

[image]